# Execution of java command in Runtime

Tags: java

```
Process process2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"javac","-g:vars","/Users/amol/Documents/Java/a.java"});
Process process3 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"javap","-l","-c","/Users/amol/Documents/Java/a"});
```

I tried to run this code but I am facing a strange problem. It compiles correctly (means the first line compiles the program) but the second line gives an error saying that `'a' not found`. However when I checked the given directory `a.class` file was created correctly. How should I correctly run the second line?

Comment: I run this code on and it works!!!

Answer (score 2):

`javap` takes a class name, not a filename. You probably want to execute:

```
javap -l -c -classpath /Users/amol/Documents/Java a
```

(Split that into string arguments appropriately, of course.)

Note that this will still fail if `a` is in a package - or if the class in `a.java` isn't actually `a` at all (which is valid for non-public classes). In both of these cases, you'd need to determine the classes involved, probably by building into an empty directory and finding out which files are produced by `javac`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked after adding the classpath argument..:)

Answer (score 1):

You may have to specify the classpath argument for javap upto the directory of the class.

```
Process process3 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"javap","-l","-c","-classpath  \"/Users/amol/Documents/Java/\"","a"});
```